# What indicated altitude should I hold at after missed approach at KTVL airport

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, instrument-procedures

Assume I'm planning on conducting the **GPS RWY 18 approach at KTVL** (Lake Tahoe airport) and the current temperature is **-40C**.  If I execute a missed approach and proceed to the holding fix (HETRY), at what indicated altitude should I hold at.

Here is the GPS RWY 18 approach chart:

[image]

Comment: https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/ntap_oct_18/part4_GEN18001.html

Comment: @BowlOfRed - trying to determine if the altitude I calculated is the same as others will calculate using the procedure in the publication you cite in your comment.

Comment: "Climbing right turn to 12000 direct HETRY WP and hold" What's temperature got to do with it?  -40C = -40F, that's pretty darn cold!

Comment: @CrossRoads - look up the meaning of the "snowflake" symbol in the upper left corner (magnified) on the plate. You'll understand what the temp has to do with the question.

Comment: Ah, cold temperature altitude correction needed. The hold altitude is >5000 ft above runway elevation, right off the chart on B1 of SW-2.  Not sure what to do in that case.

Comment: @CrossRoads - in the first comment above (BowlOfRed), click the link offered and take a look at the procedure. (by the way, it's airport elevation, not runway elevation).

Comment: Following the linked procedure I round the hold altitude to be 6000 feet above the field.  Extrapolating the -40 deg correction at 240 feet/1000 feet I get a correction of 1450 feet. Rounding that up to the next 100, I get a correction of 1500 feet.  That sets the hold at 13500 feet.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the info, I've bookmarked that site for future reference.  Not sure I'll be flying IFR when it's that cold, icing in clouds is a concern, as well as the engne not making enough heat to keep the cabin warm.  -10C on a nice clear winter day in New England was cold enough!

Comment: @CrossRoads - I think you got it, except read the 2nd paragraph below the ICAO temp chart.  It says that "No extrapolation above the 5000 fr. column is required." Therefore, the correction would be 1210 ft. added to the missed approach holding altitude (of 12000 ft.) and you get a revised holding altitude of 13210.  That's what I get. Many years ago, (1970s) I used to fly into TVL often, never saw a temp -27C or below.

Comment: @CrossRoads Is icing a concern at temps that low?

Comment: Probably not - should be frozen already, yes?  I know we'd be freezing in my plane! 8F/-10C, we had  gloves on, heavy coats and blankets wrapped around legs.